# Provisioning multiple datasources in grafana

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, influxdb

I have able to import a datasource & dashboard while building docker container for grafana. I tried creating two separate datasource.yml file (For example: datasoure1.yml and datasource2.yml) and copied in /etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources but getting the below error.

```
lvl=warn msg="[Deprecated] the datasource provisioning config is outdated. please upgrade" logger=provisioning.datasources filename=/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource1.yml
grafana_1_417873282a1 | t=2019-10-01T03:51:49+0000 
lvl=warn msg="[Deprecated] the datasource provisioning config is outdated. please upgrade" logger=provisioning.datasources filename=/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource2.yml
grafana_1_417873282a1 | t=2019-10-01T03:51:49+0000 lvl=eror msg="Server shutdown" logger=server reason="Service init failed: Datasource provisioning error: datasource.yaml config is invalid. Only one datasource per organization can be marked as default"
```

Any hint how I can achieve to have multiple datasources & dashboards?

datasource1.yml

```
datasources:
-  access: 'proxy'                       # make grafana perform the requests
   editable: true                        # whether it should be editable
   is_default: true                      # whether this should be the default DS
   name: 'test1'                        # name of the datasource
   org_id: 1                             # id of the organization to tie this datasource to
   type: 'influxdb'                      # type of the data source
   url: 'http://<ip-address>:8086'       # url of the prom instance
   database: 'db1'
   version: 1                            # well, versioning
```

datasource2.yml

```
datasources:
-  access: 'proxy'                       # make grafana perform the requests
   editable: true                        # whether it should be editable
   is_default: true                      # whether this should be the default DS
   name: 'test2'                        # name of the datasource
   org_id: 1                             # id of the organization to tie this datasource to
   type: 'influxdb'                      # type of the data source
   url: 'http://<ip-address>:8086'       # url of the prom instance
   database: 'db2'
   version: 1                            # well, versioning
```

Comment: Can you provide contents of `datasource1.yml` and `datasource2.yml`. As the error says, you can have one default datasource per organization.

Comment: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/11407

Comment: adding apiVersion: 1 solved my problem.

Comment: as per documentation by grafana when I am using isDefault and orgId, I am unable to create two datasource. Also I have used different orgId for dashboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check this [issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/11407).

> I have been the missing first line with the apiVersion: that has made
>   a difference.

```
# # config file version
apiVersion: 1
```